# OPENGL ES 2.0 texture in circle

Tags: java, opengl-es

trying to load a texture into a circle, but I have big troubles with it. This is the original texture:

[original texture](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxsIElz7hJULdzZaazNkZUJZV1k/edit?usp=sharing)

Here's the code:

```
private void circle(){
    int segments = 20;
    vertices = new float[segments * 3+6];
    texture = new float[segments * 3+6];
    float angle = (float)(2*Math.PI/segments);
    vertices[0]=0;
    vertices[1]=0;
    texture[0]=0.5f;
    texture[1]=0.5f;
    for(int i = 0; i < segments; i++){

        vertices[3+(i*3)]=(float)Math.sin(angle * i)*0.7f;
        vertices[3+(i*3+1)]=(float)Math.cos(angle*i)*0.7f;

        texture[3+(i*3)]=(float)Math.sin(angle * i)*0.5f+0.5f;
        texture[3+(i*3+1)]=(float)Math.cos(angle * i)*0.5f+0.5f;

    }
    vertices[3*segments+3]=0;
    vertices[3*segments+4]=0.7f;               
}
```

And I am getting something like this:
[my result](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxsIElz7hJULMVVIVUFPQVVPT1E/edit?usp=sharing)

What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: where did you learn to do it like this?

Comment: here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12626859/android-opengl-es-generate-a-circular-mesh-for-texture

Comment: Best guess would be that you are pushing your texture coordinates as a 2d array instead of 3d. Look at the part where you push the texture coordinate pointer to the GL.

Comment: yes, there was the problem. Thank you indeed I could't solve this issue.